# How to perform conditional column update in Django Tastypie

Tags: django, tastypie

I want to update count conditionally, if count = 1, update count = 10.

```
class HelloModel(Model):

  count = models.IntegerField()


class HelloModelResource(Resource)

  def obj_update(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
```

Is obj_update() right place to update? How to update?

Answer (score 0):

You can use condititioanl expressions and according to [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/):

> Conditional expressions can be used in annotations, aggregations, filters, lookups, and updates. They can also be combined and nested with other expressions. This allows you to make powerful conditional queries.

```
from django.db.models import F, Q, When, Case, Value
YourModel.objects.update(count=Case( When(count=1,then=Value(10)), 
  default=Value("default_value")))
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. How about obj_update(...), where to update in Tastypie?

Comment: Like to know single and multiple. Thanks.

Comment: i think in single object you can pass its id in filter and update it and multiple just like above